# Calculating Cumulative Moving Average Accuracy

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a function **f(...)** which I don't know the value of.

If i sample this function **N** times while calculating the **C**umulative **M**oving **A**verage of the return value, how can I know how accurate the calculated average is? Is there some type of indicator I can use?

I tried calculating the variance of the past **N** **CMA** samples, but I don't know that's a good indicator.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any domain knowledge of the process producing f?  If it is a natural phenomena (such as population growth), I would suggest an exponential average rather than simple average.  I would also fit a best exponential function to my data and perform residual analysis on that.

Same for weighted averages - eg, if I know the newer data more accurate than old (such as satellite data from modern satellites with better sensors than old).

I would keep variance as one metric for my analysis in any case, and just use the suggestions above as a second data point.

I suppose I would also check for heteroskedacity and/or kurtosis to help evaluate whatever model I fit to f as a third data point.

Hope some of this helps.